# Customer Data vanished after editing an order

Tags: orders, customer, sales, edit-order

We only have quest sales in our shop.
Nevertheless the customer data (name, gender, email) is set in the order - not only in addresses. This data also shows in right top corner (account information) when looking on an order in backend.

When editing an order you get an form left in account information which on our shop only includes email and gender.
After saving the edited order the new order has looses the customer name in it's account information.

I am searching for the fieldlist which creates email and gender and only found `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Account::_prepareForm()`.

Does anyone have to solve that issue too? How I could include other fields like firstname, lastname and so on.
How to prefill I know - I override the method getFormValues to preselect the gender dropdown.

Comment: This isn't the case when I edit an order, customer name just stays the same in the edited order.

Comment: @philwinkle: Is on quest or logged-in sales with real customers?

Answer (score 2):

The reason that these attributes do not show on the edit order form is because they do not have an entry in the table `customer_form_attribute` for the form code `adminhtml_checkout`

When building this form all attributes with an entry in this table for that form will be considered, they will then be ignored if the are user defined and also if they are not required.

Code for building this form can be found at `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Account::_prepareForm`

Here you can see it sets the type of form.

```
/* @var $customerForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
$customerForm   = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
$customerForm->setFormCode('adminhtml_checkout')
    ->setStore($this->getStore())
    ->setEntity($customerModel);
```

And then proceeds to get all the required system attributes:

```
foreach ($customerForm->getSystemAttributes() as $attribute) {
    /* @var $attribute Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute */
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired()) {
        $attributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
    }
}
```

When loading the attributes in `Mage_Eav_Model_Form::getAttributes()` it takes into account the form code.

```
$collection->setStore($this->getStore())
    ->setEntityType($this->getEntityType())
    ->addFormCodeFilter($this->getFormCode())
    ->setSortOrder();
```